# Where to install a python package on a Linux machine with no internet connection?

Tags: linux, python

I have to import a python library onto my Linux machine, which has no internet connection so I can’t download it with wget. I downloaded the package on my Windows machine with pip. I can connect from Windows to Linux with Putty. Where should I copy the library in Linux (if it’s compatible)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the package in the following path:

```
/usr/lib/python[version]/package-name/
```

Where `[version]` is your Linux python version you are using and `package-name` is obviously a directory with the name of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows machine to download the .whl files, copy the .whl files anywhere on the target, then run:

```
pip install path/to/*.whl
```

on the target.